Get 3D boundingbox with 2D boundingbox and LiDAR data
I'm trying to create 3D bounding boxes from 2D bounding boxes created with yolov5 and point cloud data from a lidar sensor.I'm working with ROS2 and Gazebo and as a reference I'm trying to use this method of doing it: making 3d bbs.
The goal is to cluster the points from lidar and make 3D bounding boxes for the objects that are in the 2D boundingboxes aswell.
Here is my code so far:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, LaserScan
from visualization_msgs.msg import Marker
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
import cv2
import torch
import numpy as np


class YOLOv5Detector(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('object_detector')
        self.get_logger().info('Initializing YOLOv5Detector node')

        self.bridge = CvBridge()
        self.image_width = None  # Variable to store image width
        self.lidar_data = None

        # Camera image subscription
        self.subscription_image = self.create_subscription(
            Image,
            '/drone/front/image_raw',
            self.image_callback,
            10)
        self.get_logger().info('Subscribed to /drone/front/image_raw')

        # LiDAR data subscription
        self.subscription_lidar = self.create_subscription(
            LaserScan,
            '/points_transformed',
            self.lidar_callback,
            10)
        self.get_logger().info('Subscribed to /points_transformed')

        # Bounding box marker publisher
        self.publisher = self.create_publisher(Marker, 'bounding_box', 10)
        self.get_logger().info('Publisher for bounding_box initialized')

        # Load the YOLOv5 model
        model_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/ros2_ws/src/yolov5')
        model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, 'runs/train/exp/weights/best.pt')
        self.model = torch.hub.load(model_dir, 'custom', path=model_path, source='local')
        self.get_logger().info('YOLOv5 model loaded')

    def image_callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info('Received image message')
        cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, desired_encoding='bgr8')
        self.image_width = cv_image.shape[1]  # Store image width
        results = self.model(cv_image)
        results.print()

        # Display the detection results
        cv2.imshow("YOLOv5 Detection", results.render()[0])
        cv2.waitKey(1)

        # Process detection results
        self.process_detection_results(results)

    def process_detection_results(self, results):
        if self.image_width is not None and self.lidar_data is not None:
            self.get_logger().info('Processing detection results')
            for bbox in results.xyxy[0]:
                cx = (bbox[0] + bbox[2]) / 2  # Calculate center x-coordinate
                angle = self.bbox_to_angle(cx)
                distance = self.find_corresponding_range(angle)
                self.get_logger().info(f"Object at angle {angle} is {distance} meters away.")
                if distance != float('inf'):
                    self.create_3d_bounding_box(bbox, distance, angle)

    def bbox_to_angle(self, cx):
        relative_x = (cx / self.image_width) * 2 - 1
        angle = relative_x * (self.lidar_data.angle_max - self.lidar_data.angle_min) / 2 + \
                (self.lidar_data.angle_max + self.lidar_data.angle_min) / 2
        self.get_logger().info(f"BBox center x: {cx}, Relative x: {relative_x}, Angle: {angle}")
        return angle

    def find_corresponding_range(self, angle):
        """
        Find the closest range measurement in the LiDAR scan to a given angle.
        """
        angles = np.linspace(self.lidar_data.angle_min, self.lidar_data.angle_max, len(self.lidar_data.ranges))
        index = np.argmin(np.abs(angles - angle))
        range_value = self.lidar_data.ranges[index]
        if range_value == float('inf'):
            self.get_logger().info(f"Warning: Object at angle {angle} out of LiDAR range.")
        return range_value

    def create_3d_bounding_box(self, bbox, distance, angle):
        x = distance * np.cos(angle)
        y = distance * np.sin(angle)
        z = 0  # Assuming ground level for simplicity

        # Placeholder for bounding box dimensions (width, height, depth)
        width = 1.0
        height = 1.0
        depth = 1.0

        self.get_logger().info(f"3D Bounding Box - Center: ({x}, {y}, {z}), Dimensions: ({width}, {height}, {depth})")

        # Publish bounding box as marker
        self.publish_bounding_box((x, y, z), (width, height, depth))

    def publish_bounding_box(self, center, dimensions):
        marker = Marker()
        marker.header.frame_id = "base_link"
        marker.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
        marker.ns = "bounding_boxes"
        marker.id = 0
        marker.type = Marker.CUBE
        marker.action = Marker.ADD
        marker.pose.position.x = float(center[0])
        marker.pose.position.y = float(center[1])
        marker.pose.position.z = float(center[2])
        marker.scale.x = float(dimensions[0])
        marker.scale.y = float(dimensions[1])
        marker.scale.z = float(dimensions[2])
        marker.color.a = 1.0
        marker.color.r = 1.0
        marker.color.g = 0.0
        marker.color.b = 0.0
        self.get_logger().info(f"Publishing Marker: Center=({center}), Dimensions=({dimensions})")
        self.publisher.publish(marker)

    def lidar_callback(self, msg):
        self.lidar_data = msg
        self.get_logger().info('LiDAR data received')


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    yolov5_detector = YOLOv5Detector()
    rclpy.spin(yolov5_detector)
    yolov5_detector.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

The issue I have is that I don't know why I can't see any 3d bounding boxes created.

